# Check checkbox and mark its own paragraph with jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Guys i have 2 checkboxes. When i click one of them, the paragraph under it must be marked but when i check first checkbox , it marks other paragraph also.Tried to solve with event target but could not solve it.
what is the easiest way to do it with jquery?
[JSFIDDLE HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/7enud45n/)

```js
function example ( event ) {
  var target = $( event.target );
  if ( target.is( "#checkbox" ) || target.is(":checked")) {
    $("p").addClass("checked");
  }else {
     $("p").removeClass("checked");
  }
}
  $("#checkbox").change(example);
```

```css
.item {
  border:2px solid #333;
  display:inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  text-align:center;
}
p.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <input type="checkbox" id="checkbox">
  <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.</p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your need, you can simply use the jQuery `next` function.

```
target.next('p').addClass("checked");
```

I fixed your fiddle, there was some other mistakes, for example, the id property should be unique, you cannot use id='checkbox' on two different element.

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b1z72dqv/)

```js
function example(event) {
  var target = $(event.target);
  if (target.is(":checked")) {
    target.next('p').addClass("checked");
  } else {
    target.next('p').removeClass("checked");
  }
}
$("input[type='checkbox']").change(example);
```

```css
.item {
  border: 2px solid #333;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-align: center;
}
p.checked {
  text-decoration: line-through;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="item">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
</div>

<div class="item">
  <input type="checkbox">
  <p>Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam.</p>
</div>
```

Comment: See the fixed fiddle. There was other issues in your code, feel free to ask if you need more inputs.

Answer (score 0):

$("P") will get the first paragraph of the DOM, try this:

```
function example ( event ) {
  var target = $( event.target );
  if ( target.is( "#checkbox" ) || target.is(":checked")) {
    target.next("p").addClass("checked");
  }else {
     target.next("p").removeClass("checked");
  }
}
  $("#checkbox").change(example);
```